# Can't set headers after they are sent multiple mongo queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, http-headers

I am getting the can't send headers after they are sent error. Well I have tried removing everything I could and it fails. My route is below, and I do know it is not the most efficient way of doing it but don't know a better way.

I would ideally be able to do the `res.redirect("/dashboard/it/model");` where each of the blank lines are, that is what I had at first. I removed them and had the same error so I commented out the `setRender` which is pretty much a `res.render()`. I am not sure what else I could change to make this work. I need to go through each of the queries simply so I don't have to create 13 different routes. I can do that if need be but rather have it all in one place.

Route:

```
// delete model  
  app.delete('/dashboard/it/model/delete/:id',
    // setRender('dashboard/it/model'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => {
      AP.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Cable.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      DeskPhone.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Desktop.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Laptop.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      MobilePhone.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Monitor.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Printer.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Projector.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Router.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Switch.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Tablet.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      });
      Custom.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){

      } else {

      }
      res.redirect("/dashboard/it/model");
      });
      next();
    },
    dashboard.getDefault);
```

Comment: Well, you don't show ANY code that sends a response, so it's not like we can find where you're sending more than one response for a given request.  You will have to show your actual code for us to help.  For a general idea of what causes this error, there are hundreds of questions on this topic.

Comment: Really unclear what you are trying to do here. Of course trying to "send a response" in multiple places is just wrong and why you get the error when you attempt it. You want **ONE** response, regardless of how many actions are applied. What is basically unclear is whether it really is your intent to attempt to remove from ALL of the provided models, or in fact if you simply want to REMOVE FROM EVERY model registered, Moreover is the WHY? Questions usually benefit from a context of "Why?". Please explain.

Comment: Provide the if and else block statements because if you send response in each and every if else that might be a problem

Comment: @jfriend00 That is my actual code, just copy and pasted it in then formatted it for Stack Overflow. At the very bottom of the code there is `res.redirect("/dashboard/it/model");` and above there is `// setRender('dashboard/it/model'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),` So there is a response in there.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have it so all of these models are looped out onto a page each with a delete button. I want it to delete the one with the ID of the row / delete button has. I want it to then go to `/dashboard/it/model` weather that be a render or redirect, I rather a redirect though. I have gotten it all to work on different pages. The issue is the multiple queries in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one simple problem I see (don't know if it's the only problem because you've left out lots of the code) is that you are doing a `res.redirect()` and you are calling `next()`.  You need to do one or the other, not both.

`res.redirect()` sends a 302 response.  Then, calling `next()` allows other middleware or handlers to also process the request and one of them will likely send a response too.  Attempting to send more than one response to the same request is what causes the error you see.

So, if you're going to redirect, then do not call next.

---

Also, if you're going to do a `res.redirect()` or `next()` like you are, then you can't also send a response in any of your `if/else` clauses.  Since you don't explain the purpose of that code, we can't really guess how that is supposed to work.  The key principle here is that you send one and only one response per request.  Sending any more than one triggers the error you see.

Comment: I might be interpretting the question incorrectly, but *"I would ideally be able to do the res.redirect("/dashboard/it/model"); **where each of the blank lines are**,..."* seemed to indicate to me that the OP was trying to do that in "every call" to each model. So "my presumption" was that the misconception was "chaining" and returning one response. Of course I too was keeping the note in the back of my mind about `next()` likely altering the response, and half concocted a note that this "appeared" to be a "cargo cult" rather than something needed.

Comment: @NeilLunn - That's why I prefaced my answer the way I did.  When they don't show us all the real and relevant code, sometimes we can only go on what we can see.  Anything else is a guess.  But, this one issue IS a problem to be fixed.  Still could be other issues in the real code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you it was the `next();` call, I thought i needed it for the `dashboard.getDefault`. As for leaving out code, I did include my whole route and explained what the relevant middlware did. What else should I have added?

Comment: @NeilLunn You were right on what I was asking, I can see the issue was me. I didn't really know enough about doing multiple queries in this way to know how to ask. I did mark jfriend00's answer as correct as it solved my issue and gave me the desired result.